# Will Intel HD graphic benefit RDP only server?

Tags: remote-desktop, xeon

For my new software developing company , I am deciding to purchase one of the following Intel XEON processor

```
INTEL E3 1230 V3  (No intel HD cheaper by ~ $30)
INTEL E3 1245 V3 (Intel® HD Graphics P4600)
```

There will be 6-8 clients connected through RDP in LAN  , working on LAMP stack and using Eclipse IDE for PHP .

Should I invest in graphics or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows requires some sort of graphics output. Without in-CPU graphics, you cannot utilize most motherboard's video connectors. Some server-grade boards have a “dedicated” GPU onboard.

So, rather than looking at the RDP aspect, you should simply consider the following question: **Does your machine have graphics capabilities without in-CPU support?**

If the answer is **no**, buy a CPU with integrated graphics.

If the answer is **yes**, don't.

Things like RemoteFX are probably not what you're working towards, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'No'.

RDP runs a very limited graphics driver on the server which instead of sending 'images' of the actual screen, it merely sends instructions which get rendered on the client computer.

Compare this to VNC, which, essentially records the screen and sends it down the pipe, and sends your input back up. It can do some decent compression but it'll always be slow compared to RDP.

Using VNC, you would see benefit from having better graphics support installed on the server, however this is offset by the higher latency and greater amounts of data required to display effectively the same thing.

For simple graphic requirements like yours, stick with RDP and don't worry about the graphics support.